# Run Outlook VBA code without being logged into the client

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code in a non-person mailfile.  I need it to run without anyone being logged into that Outlook account.  It saves Excel attachments to a network share (see below).  It is currently set to run as a rule against all new incoming mails.

---

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat
dateFormat = Format(Now, "mmdd H-mm")

saveFolder = "C:\Test\One"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
  If Right(objAtt.FileName, 3) = "xls" Or Right(objAtt.FileName, 4) = "xlsx" Then
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

---

Is it possible to automate this rule to run without being logged into an Outlook client?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

"Because Outlook Visual Basic for Applications code runs on the client, Outlook must be running for the code to run."

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324568